# installing sqlite3 on ubuntu not playing nice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, sqlite

When trying to install this through jenkins on Ubuntu, I'm running into some issues.  I've added all of the required files from apt for sqlite and bundler, vendored gems.

bundle exec rake -T --trace
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136: warning: Insecure world writable dir /var/lib/jenkins/jobs in PATH, mode 040777
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in`rescue in '
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in`require'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/Rakefile:5:in`require'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in`load'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in`raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in`block in run'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in`run'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in`load'
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/invited-tests/workspace/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `'

## gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.21)
rake (0.9.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.4)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)

(I could remove any or both of the above gems, same issue).

## rvm --version

rvm 1.5.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

## ruby -v

ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]

Anything else?

Comment: For this particular issue, unvendoring the gems worked to get passed this issue.

rm -rf .bundle/
bundle install

After this, you may be able to revendor, but haven't gotten there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unvendoring the gems and setting up RVM and a specific gemset for this environment worked here.  I would suggest letting the gems compile with native extensions in the future.

We are also removing  sqlite3 from the test environment totally once we have postgres or our production similar database going.