# rvm, ubuntu 11.10 gem preventing server from starting up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, twilio

I've been banging my head up against a wall on this problem for the past day or two.  (I have only been using Linux for a week, and Ruby for 7 months so go easy on me, but I asked a few developers, and no dice, so it sounds like its a real issue).

I have rvm installed with Ruby 1.9.2, and Rails 3.1.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.  Everything worked fine while I was coding in windows 7.

Here's the issue: When I run `rails server`, I get the following:

```
$ rails server
 /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require': no such file to load -- twilio/ruby (LoadError)
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `rescue in block in require'
```

this goes on for a while.  This is weird to me, because, I searched my app for the line "twilio/ruby" and I couldn't find it.

I found these links, where it looks like people had similar issues, but I either couldn't understand what they were saying, or was too afraid to adopt their suggestion to my use in fear of messing up my environment further.

- https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1531
- [installing sqlite3 on ubuntu not playing nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058030/installing-sqlite3-on-ubuntu-not-playing-nice)

Also, one developer told me to do the following:

1. `cd` to my project directory
2. `rvm use 1.9.2`
3. `bundle install`
4. `rails server`

But that didn't work either.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. That means your code is using the twilio gem somewhere, but it hasn't been bundled before starting the app. What I would do for starters is to cd to your root dir and run gem install twilio. So that twilio is installed to your gem dir (globally)

Comment: nope, that didn't work, it just led to the same result when I did rails server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the app for "twilio-ruby' or just 'twilio'. Seeing as its bundler that's throwing the exception it should be in there... Otherwise it could be a dependency of another gem.
If you do 'gem list -d twilio' what do you get back?

Comment: gem list -d twilio-ruby

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

twilio-ruby (3.5.1)
    Author: Andrew Benton
    Homepage: http://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby
    Installed at: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318

    A simple library for communicating with the Twilio REST API,
    building TwiML, and generating Twilio Client Capability Tokens

Comment: yea, i certainly do require "twilio-ruby" in a couple of my controllers.

Comment: Sorry, guess my above post was confusing, twilio is a gem I use, and I have "gem twilio-ruby" in my gemfile, it just never caused me issues before.

Comment: Just to be really picky, what do you get for 'bundle exec rails server'

Comment: If you've just changed to ruby 1.9.2 or the new version of ruby gems expect lots of gems to get upset

Comment: I get the same error message when I do bundle exec rails server.

Comment: also, I have ruby 1.9.2 in my windows environment (just confirmed that its running on localhost) and I don't run into an issue.

Comment: Check the versions of gem -v and rake -v for me please?

Comment: gem version is 1.8.19, rake -v led to "rake aborted! no such file to load --twilio/ruby"

Comment: possible incompatibility between gem -v > 1.5.x, try removing v 1.8.19 and installing one of: 1.5.x, 1.6.x or 1.7.x and try again?